# Сложение чисел из трёх таблиц

Tags: php, mysql

Друзья, есть такой запрос

```
SELECT `count_lb` + `count_pr`  AS `kek` FROM disciplain  WHERE `group`='.$value['id']
```

Складываем всё отлично, но если в одной ил таблицы будет `NULL`, то и показывает он соответственно `NULL`. Подскажите пожалуйста, как в моём случае правильно применить функцию `IFNULL` для проверки пустых полей.

Comment: если функцию нашли, неужели сложно посмотреть как оно применяется? `IFNULL(count_lb, 0) + IFNULL(count_pr, 0)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Попробуйте использовать IFNULL

```
select 4 + IFNULL(NULL,0);
```

то есть

```
SELECT IFNULL(`count_lb`,0) + IFNULL(`count_pr`,0)  AS `kek`
```

см. http://rustyrazorblade.com/2006/09/mysql-number-null-null/